# my link_to doesn't pass through the controller rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a problem with Rails 7. My `link_to` doesn't pass through the controller and it gives me error obviously in the `_form` I post the codes:

**Routes**

```
  resources :contents
```

**Contents_controller.rb**

```
def new
    byebug
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.nome_azienda != nil || current_user.piva != nil
      @content = current_user.contents.build
    else
      redirect_to user_path(current_user.id), notice: "Per accedere alla vendita devi    compilare il modulo Profilo " 
    end
  end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="center">Inserimento Offerta</h1>

<%= render 'form', content: @content %>

<div class="container">
  <%= link_to 'Indietro', contents_path %>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: content) do |form| %>
  <% if content.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(content.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this content from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% content.errors.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error it gives me is as follows

```
NoMethodError at /contents/new
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Hint: Something is `nil` when it probably shouldn't be.
```

Comment: Your controller file should be named `contents_controller.rb`.

Comment: Sorry about the typing error contents_controller.rb

Comment: do you have a `current_user` in that controller? your checks before the redirect don't look like they catch the scenario where there is no `current_user`

Comment: Yes, I have a current_user but on the error screen my Current_user is loaded. @current_user 

#<User id: 1, email: "brontolo6578@gmail.com", created_at: "2022-01-01 17:12:54.375841000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-01-07 10:54:41.080017000 +0000", name: "Flavio", admin: true, azz_pri: "1", nome_pri: "Flavio", cognome: "Fronto", indirizzo: "FER", num: "34", cap: "75020", citta: "Caprarico", prov: "na", telefono: "33333333", telefono_2: "333333333", piva: "12122", codfis: "chsal", nome_azienda: "La mia Azienda", email_1: nil, pec: "pec", stripe_customer_id: "cus_Ksx2mrMywCfVeA", slug: nil

Comment: If you place `<%= @content.to_json %>` right before the link to the form, and remove the form link temporarily `<%# render 'form', content: @content %>` what do you see?

Comment: I have tried null

Comment: I have tried with edit I have added a byebug but on edit it crashes with new no it does not go through at all